# Combine multiple elements and append result to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function setParagraph(paraList) {

    $.each(paraList, function (i, field) {

        var pElement = document.createElement('p');
        $(pElement).text(field);

        //a line that combines the p elements like so:
        //<p>First para</p>
        //<p>Second para</p>
    });

    return //all elements for append;
}
```

I am trying to write code with minimum number of lines to return a "collection" of p elements that needs to be appended to the following div:

```
$("#somediv").append(setParagraph(jsonValue));
```

To produce:

```
<div id="somediv">
    <p>First para</p>
    <p>Second para</p>
</div>
```

The method `setParagraph` is passed json string with collection of string items that are translated into p elements in the method.

I have tried pushing the elements into an array but I don't think that is the right way to go.
Also, I do not wish to use string concatenation in the loop to produce the desired results, unless of course that is the only best way to handle it.

**EDIT:**

The below works but as I said I am looking for some other solution besides array:

```js
function setParagraph(paraList) {

    var arrElements = [];

    $.each(paraList, function (i, field) {

        var $pElement = $("<p/>").text(field);

        arrElements.push($pElement);
    });

    return arrElements;
}

var jsonValue = ["First para","Second para"];
$("#somediv").append(setParagraph(jsonValue));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="somediv">
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: Also `var $pElement = $("<p/>").text(field);`

Comment: Added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.map(..)` for that, here is an example:

```js
function setParagraph(paraList) {
  return $.map(paraList, function(item) {
    return $("<p>", {
      text: item
    });
  });
}

$("#somediv").append(setParagraph(["one", "two", "three"]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="somediv"></div>
```

Comment: That could be [so much shorter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59642058/295783)

Answer (score 2):

Shorter

```js
const par = ["one", "two", "three"]
$("#somediv").html(par.map(p =>  $("<p>", { text: p })))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="somediv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple fiddle example that I think would suit your needs. It works in a different way, a little bit at least, but with a bit of changing you'd get your desired result.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fkoLn4v9/

Here's the code:

```
// index.js 
const paragraphsCollection = [
  {
    tag: 'p',
    content: 'This is the first parargraph',
  },
  {
    tag: 'p',
    content: 'This is the second paragraph',
  },
];

const setParagraph = (parentElem, contentData) => {
    contentData.forEach(({ tag, content }) => {
          const domElem = document.createElement(tag);
            domElem.innerText = content;

            parentElem.appendChild(domElem);
        });
};

const divElem = document.querySelector('.parentDiv');

setParagraph(divElem, paragraphsCollection);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parentDiv"></div>
```